# What tool can get the Technic pin out from a connection closed in the other end?

Tags: technic, disassembly, tools

I'm having trouble removing these LEGO Technic pins apart from their connectors and I don't want to use carpenter tools like pliers which may damage the bricks.

[image: pieces to separate easily and safely]

What tool can get the pieces separated without force that damages the pieces or my fingers?

Comment: always used muh teef in such conditions ;)

Comment: Finger nails typically work for me lol!

Comment: I would have said...uh...your bare hands. But I suppose you tried that already. ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Push the Technic pin in a beam hole, then insert a rod (antenna or minifig tool handle) into the hole in the pin from the other side. The rod will prevent the "lips" of the pin from closing in, therefore preventing the pin from leaving the beam. Then you can pull on anything attached to the other end of the pin.

This example below shows the removal of a pin from a beam:

[image: Example image with two beams]

Comment: Heh, beat you by *that* much.. probably the time it took you to type a fuller explanation. :)

Comment: Oh now look at you with your fancy pictures! :)

Comment: Thank you for your fast tip! I found a solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 9):

I figured out a solution while waiting for answers. The tool I used for it was a universal T20 bit which most people have or can easily get access to. I took some documenting pictures of it which I would like to share here.

EDIT: Use a plastic LEGO rod as *zovits* and others recommend. If you don't have that, use metal tools as a last resort. And if using a metal tool, use **Allen** a.k.a. **Hex** key instead of **Torx**. as *PlasmaHH* commented.
[image: set up]
[image: put the pin in the hole]
[image: put the T20 in the hole]
[image: pull them apart]

Comment: Hard to argue with results, but I'm reluctant to apply metal tools when plastic will do. :)

Comment: The results were good. I tried to take a photo of the inside but it was too blurry and dark. I don't have the laser beam but would for sure use it before the metal tool which is not round. SO my tip might help out those without the full lego brick set up.

Comment: Please use allen wrenches, not torx.

Answer (score 6):

Stick the pin end into a Technic hole (like in the middle of those two red bits), then stick a light saber rod into the pin, and pull the red bit.

BOOM.

Comment: Thank you for your fast tip! I found a solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 4):

I recently noticed that LEGO included guidance on this exact issue in their instructions in the late 80s and early 90s. Here's an example from the 1989 Universal Building Set (8034):

[image: 8034 Instruction page 1]

Here's the bit referring to disassembling these sorts of elements:

[image: 8034 pin disassembly diagram]

Comment: Nice! This was actually my first Lego Technic set, forgot it until I saw the images. Nostalgia!

Comment: @Tim That's great! It's a fun set. My son and I just dug it out of my collection to rebuild.